# synchronize on "this" vs specific resource

Tags: java, concurrency

I would like to understand which approach is correct/better performant, using synchronized method or synchronized on specific resource?
My understanding is that acquiring lock on specific object for which the concurrent modification needs to be avoided will be faster as all the other threads which are trying to modify other objects are free to proceed.

Example below code is synchronized on this for "createSession" method

```java
class Solution {

    public String getSessionKey(int user) {
        if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
        throw new InvalidSessionException(SESSION_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    public synchronized String createSession(int user) {
        if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
        UserSession session = new UserSession(user, generateSessionId(), LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        someConcurrentHashMap.put(user, session);
        sessionKeyToUser.put(session.getKey(), user);
        return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
    }

    public int getUserBySessionKey(String sessionKey) {
        return sessionKeyToUser.getOrDefault(sessionKey, -1);
    }

}
```

Below code acquires lock on specific object if it exists else on this.

```java
class Solution {

    private final Object createSessionLock = new Object();

    public String getSessionKey(int user) {
        if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
        throw new InvalidSessionException(SESSION_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    public String createSession(int user) {
        // if user exists then synchronized on the user object
        // else synchronized on lock object
        if (someConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(user)) {
            return createForExistingUser(user);
        }
        return createForNewUser(user);
    }


    public int getUserBySessionKey(String sessionKey) {
        return sessionKeyToUser.getOrDefault(sessionKey, -1);
    }

    private String createForExistingUser(int user) {
        if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
        UserSession userSession = someConcurrentHashMap.get(user);
        synchronized (userSession) {
            if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
                return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
            }
            UserSession session = new UserSession(user, generateSessionId(), LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
            someConcurrentHashMap.put(user, session);
            sessionKeyToUser.put(session.getKey(), user);
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
    }

    private String createForNewUser(int user) {
        if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
        synchronized (createSessionLock) {
            if (validateSessionKey(user)) {
                return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
            }
            UserSession session = new UserSession(user, generateSessionId(), LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
            someConcurrentHashMap.put(user, session);
            sessionKeyToUser.put(session.getKey(), user);
            return someConcurrentHashMap.get(user).getKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This are not equivalent or comparable. Whether or not one or the other is correct or better depends a lot on context. Your second code is formally incorrect (though likely not in an observable way), because you use two different locks for operations with a `UserSession`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "Your second code is formally incorrect" I would like to understand more, please elaborate. This is my thought, if a user exists I can acquire lock on the object because that is the object I want to save from race condition, if the user does not exist I have to prevent access to "createSession" because that is the only way to make sure only one user is created with same ID.

Comment: You use the session itself as a monitor in once case, and createSessionLock in the other. Monitor locks establish happens-before relations, but in there won't be such a relation between creating a new user session and the first operation on that session afterwards, so formally there could be race conditions or other visibility issues. If `someConcurrentHashMap` is really a `ConcurrentHashMap`, that problem is mitigated. The fact you use a `ConcurrentHashMap` could also be an indication that a solution without using `synchronized` might be possible.

Comment: What does `validateSessionKey(user)` do?

Comment: @Holger it check when was the session created and returns boolean result based on that

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that acquiring lock on specific object for which the concurrent modification needs to be avoided will be faster as all the other threads which are trying to modify other objects are free to proceed.

I think you could be *mis*-understanding the idea of [*fine-grained locking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)#Granularity). Suppose you have a program in which a large body of data is shared by multiple threads. Suppose also that different threads often only want to access small parts of that data, and often those parts don't overlap.

You face a choice: It's easy and foolproof to use just one lock, to protect the entire database. But it can be more efficient to have many locks that each protect a small part of it. The first way is the most extreme version of *coarse grained locking,* and the second way is "fine grained." Fine-grained locking may be more efficient, but it means more work for you the programmer: More code to write, more code to test. And, if different threads sometimes *do* need to access overlapping parts of the database, then fine-grained locking carries the risk of deadlock.

---

I think the part that you might not understand is the significance of which objects you choose to use as locks.

In Java there is *no* significance to which object you choose to use as a lock. In Java, when one thread enters a `synchronized (foobar)` block, the only thing it prevents is, it prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object, `foobar`, at the same time.  In particular, it does *not* prevent other threads from *accessing* foobar.

Synchronizing on some object is completely independent from using the same object in any other way.

---

The *real* argument against using so-called "synchronized methods" is that when you do it, the object on which you are synchronizing most likely is a publicly visible object.

If your `class Solution` with its `public synchronized String createSession(...)` method is part of a library, then that opens the possibility that some client of your library could use a `Solution` instance as a lock. It wouldn't be a smart idea for them to do it, but they are *allowed* to do it. And, if they do it, then their code is using the same object for locking that your code uses. That could lead to weird interactions between their code and yours.

What's worse, is. If you later change *when* your code synchronizes on a `Solution` instance, it could *break* their code when they upgrade to the newest version of your library.

If, instead you only ever synchronize on `private final Object lock=new Object()` objects, then you avert that problem, and maybe reinforce the illusion among your library clients that your library is "robust" and "reliable."

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand that synchronizing on object does not prevent other threads from modifying it in a non synchronizing block, but given the fact that there are no code block other than the one synchronized on the object can modify the object, fine grained lock will be better than coarse grained lock.

Comment: @Sagar it seems, you still don’t understand. In your second code, the threads are synchronizing *on different objects*. The synchronization has no effect at all.

Comment: @Holger "the threads are synchronizing on different objects" yes, I know synchronization on the "userSession" object prevent other threads from entering the synchronized block using the same  "userSession" object. " The synchronization has no effect at all." please explain, I have test cases which invokes this method concurrently and I did not observe any issue (race condition etc.)

Comment: @Sagar “I did not observe any issue” is not a proof for correctness at all. But as Mark Rotteveel said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598382/73599601?noredirect=1#comment129967366_73598382) you might get away with flawed synchronization if the synchronization is actually obsolete. Your code constructs a new `UserSession` object, which is always completely initialized when observed through the `ConcurrentHashMap`. However, the code does not guard against obsolete overlapping creations of new `UserSession` objects for the same user.

Comment: @Holger thanks for taking time to explain, but I still do not see any practical issues of this approach. I did find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134998/is-it-reasonable-to-synchronize-on-a-local-variable. Please let me know if there is any literature I can  go thru, specifically about this.

Comment: @Sagar since your question also is about efficiency, the better solution is to remove synchronization when not needed. When using the `ConcurrentHashMap` consistently, you can eliminate all flaws of your current solution and even avoid performing multiple lookups. Re: literature, I think “Java Concurrency in Practice”, ISBN 978-0321349606 still is one of the best resources.

Comment: thanks @Holger , I think i will have to read it again :) .

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to go with the *synchronized on specific resource*. If we are going to *synchronize* in method level then a lot of threads will be in waiting state and also there will be possible situation where a lot of things inside a method that can be access by multiple threads leaving only the *important block of code that requires thread safety* which does not make sense. Most of the time we can go with resource level *synchronize* to efficiently utilise the available resources.